# How to solve the error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, keras, onnx

Hi I want to convert my model in python 3.8 and TensorFlow==2.2.0 and Keras==2.4.0 with LSTM nodes to onnx file by keras2onnx, but as soon as I run the code for converting I got this error. I searched on the net and someone suggested putting the input. Shape in the LSTM node, I checked that, but nothing happened. Could you please tell me what should I do?

```
import keras
from keras import models 
import numpy as np
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as  tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, BatchNormalization, Activation, Embedding
from keras import callbacks
from keras import layers
tensorflow.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
# Read the scrambled data
dataread = DataReader()
data_array, fin_risk = dataread.get_shuffle_data()

batchsz = 1024  # Batch
val_size = 1800  # Validation set size

train_db = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_array[val_size:, :, :], fin_risk[val_size:]))   # Divide the training set

val_db = tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_array[:val_size, :, :], fin_risk[:val_size]))    # Divide the validation set
train_db = train_db.batch(batchsz)
val_db = val_db.batch(batchsz)
print(train_db)  # ((None, 23, 102), (None,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>
print(val_db)

  model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10))
    #model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LSTM(units,input_shape=(None,3,6), return_sequences=True, activation="tanh"))
    #model.add(LSTM(units, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True, unroll=True))
    model.add(LSTM(units,activation="tanh"))
    #model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
```

The Onnx code:

```
import onnx
import keras2onnx
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model

onnx_model_name = 'N_256_T3.onnx'
model = load_model('logs/last3.h5')
onnx_model = keras2onnx.convert_keras(model, model.name)
onnx.save_model(onnx_model, onnx_model_name)
```

and Error is :

```
tf executing eager_mode: True
tf.keras model eager_mode: False
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 11
      8 onnx_model_name = 'N_256_T3.onnx'
     10 model = load_model('logs/last3.h5')
---> 11 onnx_model = keras2onnx.convert_keras(model, model.name)
     12 onnx.save_model(onnx_model, onnx_model_name)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\python_3_8_backup\lib\site-packages\keras2onnx\main.py:62, in convert_keras(model, name, doc_string, target_opset, channel_first_inputs, debug_mode, custom_op_conversions)
     60 output_dict = {}
     61 if is_tf2 and is_tf_keras:
---> 62     tf_graph = build_layer_output_from_model(model, output_dict, input_names, output_names)
     63 else:
     64     tf_graph = model.outputs[0].graph if is_tf2 else keras.backend.get_session().graph

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\python_3_8_backup\lib\site-packages\keras2onnx\_parser_tf.py:304, in build_layer_output_from_model(model, output_dict, input_names, output_names)
    302     return extract_outputs_from_subclassing_model(model, output_dict, input_names, output_names)
    303 else:
--> 304     graph = model.outputs[0].graph
    305     output_names.extend([n.name for n in model.outputs])
    306     output_dict.update(extract_outputs_from_inbound_nodes(model))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I'd start investigation your `model = load_model()` portion, is it successfully loading the model? If yes, is it converting properly till the point you call it on line 304. `NoneType` usually pops up when something prior errored and returned nothing.

Comment: Looking at the stack it tries to access `model.outputs[0]` and it seams that `model.outputs is None`

Comment: Yes, I even put the keras2onnx.convert_keras(model, model.name) directly in the code without need to save and load that and got the error.  Is it possible the error come from this part of the code which I used TensorFlow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices? With which code can I replace that?